# QMYSQL not loaded and not available too

Tags: c++, qt

I want to connect my c++ application to a phpmyadmin DB but the program doesn't work. The problem is that when i launch this code:

```cpp
      db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
      db.setUserName("root");
      db.setPassword("");
      db.setDatabaseName("fooo");
```

I tried to add mysql.dll and mysqld.dll to folders bin and plugins/sql located in Qt folder but this is not enought.
The Application Output is:
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: You need to build the Qt driver from source. Or use MySQL conncetor